# Developing a form designer for a scripting language, how to correctly handle the custom classes

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to develop a custom form designer for a scripting language. The controls' properties and behavior are very very similar to the windows forms controls.

I know that design such application is not an easy task and develop it from scratch is a little to advanced for me. So I googled for it and found lots of examples in c# for custom forms designers.

I picked this one to work on top of it:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163634.aspx

Most of the windows controls properties won't be used, and some will be new. Let's take a button as example, I won't need many propertie like AllowDrop, Tag, etc. Some will be new, like ControllerType and BehaviorType. Others are preety much the same but with other name, like Location which will turn to be Position.

The best approach I could think of is to create a new class derived from Button and create these new properties on this class.

I managed to implement all this but now I have a problem with the PropertyGrid. Since I'm not using most base class properties, I would like to hide them on the PropertyGrid, and if possible, rename the properties that have a diferent name. I cannot control the attributes of the base class to set [Browsable(false)].

So my questions are:

1) Is this approach I'm following correct, or is there a better one?

2) Can I control the PropertyGrid behavior like what I need or do I need to develop a custom propertygrid?

3) If I can't run away from creating a custom PropertyGrid, could someone hint me on how to do this?